# Xcode 4.4.1, developer name in copyright notice

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, xcode4.4

With earlier version of Xcode I had a problem with Xcode writing "MyCompanyName" in copyright notices, but I fixed it by writing company name in my card in Address Book. Now I updated Xcode to 4.4.1 and another problem appeared: Xcode started using my login name instead of full name in copyright notices. Example:

```
//  Created by Kreiri on 8/20/12.
```

How can I make Xcode automatically use my full name again? I don't want to create custom template, I just want Xcode 4.4.1 use the same info that Xcode 4.3 used.

Answer (score 4):

Since Xcode 4.4.1 they have changed the way that works. Now it's using the *Organization* property of your Xcode project.

You can edit it by selecting the project in the *Project Navigator* (left sidebar), then in the *Utilities sidebar* (right sidebar) you find it under *Project Documentation*.

Source: http://zanshin.net/2012/08/31/xcode-project-template-copyright-fixed/

Comment: I tried setting "Organization" in "Project Document" options of my existing project to my name. With this setting new files use my name in "Copyright" line, and "Created" line still has login name.